# Why does adding more components in parallel increase the current?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, charge

Why does adding more components in parallel increase the current? Shouldn't the charges be more distributed, so they can't 'push' each other at the same rate anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Conductors are full of charges. There is not a small "stock" that is to be distributed.

The current is the flow of charges: more current doesn't usually mean more charges, but more "throughput". Also, current is not the result of charges "pushing" each other; it comes from charges undergoing an electric field.

The current increases *at fixed voltage*, just like the water flow out of a leaking barrel increases with the number of holes *at fixed water height in the barrel*.

Answer (score 1):

A water circuit analogy might help.
Think of the battery as a water pump which keeps a constant pressure difference (potential difference) between the ends of a pipe (resistor) through which water flows (current).
The pump recycles the water around a closed circuit which just consists of the pipe and the water pipe.
If another identical pipe (resistor) is placed in parallel with the original pipe (resistor) and the pressure difference kept constant (same battery) then twice as much water (current) will flow around the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding resistors in parallel reduces the effective resistance. You can perhaps think of it as more possible paths for the current to flow.

Comment: I see, but I thought copper wires had some resistance, so shouldn't adding more components and wires increase the resistance and lower the current? I don't understand why the 'effective resistance' would decrease.